# I wanted to add multiple containers in horizontal list view but not able to add in this code can any one let me know how to do

Tags: flutter, dart

wanted to add multiple containers in horizontal grid view
and this is the code i tried but iam only to achieve only one record to display not multiple.

Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
children: [
Container(
//color: Colors.blue,
child: IconButton(
// Use the EvaIcons class for the IconData
icon: weatherIcon, onPressed: () {},
),
),
Text(
sTemprature + " \u2103",
textAlign: TextAlign.left,
style: TextStyle(
fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
fontSize: 14.sp,
color: AppTheme.grey,
),
),
],
)
],

```
  ),
  children: [

    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, left: 10.w, right: 10.w),
      child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
          color: Colors.white,
          elevation: 10,
          child:
          Row(
            children: [
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 5.h, left: 10.w, right: 0.w),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                          width: 70.w,
                          height: 70.h,
                          //color: Colors.red,
                          child: weatherIconInside
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '$weatherDesc',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 14.sp,
                          letterSpacing: 0.2,
                          color: AppTheme.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
              ),
              Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 5.h, left: 20.w, right: 0.w),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Min',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 16.sp,
                          letterSpacing: 0.2,
                          color: AppTheme.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '18 ' + '\u2103',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 24.sp,
                          letterSpacing: 0.2,
                          color: AppTheme.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border(
                            bottom: BorderSide(
                                color: Colors.black, width: 10.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Max',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 16.sp,
                          letterSpacing: 0.2,
                          color: AppTheme.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        '28 ' + '\u2103',
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                          fontSize: 24.sp,
                          letterSpacing: 0.2,
                          color: AppTheme.grey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10.h,)
                    ],
                  )
              ),
            ],
          )
      ),
    )
  ],
),
```

);
}

```
i was calling 5 days wheather api and wanted to display in horizontal grid view in list
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your each Column widget with Flexible Widget.